# callback function with pointer

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

I'm using a library in C that works with a callback as a parameter, see this super simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "axgmb.h"

    void callback(interrupt_handler pointer) {
        printf("*****[APP]%lx , %lx\n", pointer.data, pointer.value); 
    }

    int main(void)
        {
            AXGMB_DIO_Open(); 
            AXGMB_DIO_interruptHandler(callback); 
            sleep(1);
            AXGMB_DIO_Close();
            return ERR_Success;
        };
```

interrupt_handler is a structure like this:

```
typedef struct interrupt_handler{
    unsigned long
    unsigned long
    unsigned long
    unsigned long
}interrupt_handler;
```

I'm trying to use it with Python 2.7, so far I wrote this:

```
mydll = windll.LoadLibrary("AGP2_API.dll")

@c.CFUNCTYPE(None, c.c_char_p)
def callBackTest(a):
    print("Test call back "+str(a))

iRet=mydll.AXGMB_DIO_Open()
mydll.AXGMB_DIO_interruptHandler(callBackTest)
time.sleep(10)
mydll.AXGMB_DIO_Close()
```

It works, in the sense that the call back is called correctly, but I'm not able to get the right data I need to, I wrote just str(a) to see if something comes out.
I have to use struct to read the data but I have no clue, I come up with something like this but not sure, and not sure how to use it:

```
class testStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('val1', c_longdouble),
                ('val2', c_longdouble),
                ('val3', c_longdouble),
                ('val4', c_longdouble)]
```

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  please correct

Comment: the posted code `#include`s a home grown file: "axgmb.h" however, the contents of that file are not posted.  How do you expect us to debug your problem if you do not post a [mcve]